# preg_replace (PHP function)

Tags: php

How do I use the values "returned" by preg_replace like in the following?

```
preg_replace($pattern, function('$1','$2'), $contents);
```

So it will pass the matches instead of $1 and $2 as strings ('$1' and '$2');

Answer (score 2):

If `function('$1','$2')` really is a function call, then you cannot do it like that. It would be called before `preg_replace` is executed. In this case, you can use **[`preg_replace_callback`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)**:

```
function foo($matches) {
    // $matches[1] is $1
    // $matches[2] is $2
}

preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'foo', $contents);
```

If it is not a function call, you have to explain better what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
$pattern = '/blabla/e'; //make sure to use the 'e' modifier
$result = preg_replace($pattern, "function('\\1', '\\2')", $contents);
```

Comment: A side note: do not use the e-modifier unless you absolutely have to.